# R: How to conditionally mark red in the exact same positions from another reactable

Tags: r, reactable

I have two reactables: one from `avg_sepal` and the other from `avg_petal` which are both defined in my code.

The first reactable is based on `avg_sepal` which marks cells conditionally in red:[image]

So the red cells are in the following positions:
`(row 1, column 2)` and `(row 3, column 2)`

My question is **how do you mark red in the exact same positions in another reactable** `avg_petal`.

Desired output:

[image]

```
library(tidyverse)
library(reactable)

## sepal group by
avg_sepal <- iris %>% 
  group_by(Species) %>% 
  summarise(
    avg_sepal_length = mean(Sepal.Length),
    avg_sepal_width = mean(Sepal.Width)
    )

## petal group by
avg_petal <- iris %>% 
  group_by(Species) %>% 
  summarise(
    avg_petal_length = mean(Petal.Length),
    avg_petal_width = mean(Petal.Width)
    )

## sepal reactable 
reactable(
  avg_sepal,
  columns = set_names(x = colnames(avg_sepal)) %>% 
    keep(~ .x %in% colnames(avg_sepal)[-1]) %>% 
    map(~ {
      colDef(
        style = function(value) {
          ds_color <- ifelse(between(value, 2.9, 3.5), "red", "white")
          list(background = ds_color)
        }
      )
    })
)

## petal reactable 
reactable(avg_petal)
```